# PHP Oracle OCI - Uploading into BLOB

Tags: php, database, oracle, blob

What am I doing wrong here to insert a file upload into a BLOB field.

I check the KB of the blob file after inserting and it results to 0.

```
// retrieve image file from form

$file1 = $_FILES['movie']['name']; // MOVIE UPLOAD
$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['movie']['tmp_name']);



$sql = "INSERT INTO SCHEMA_A.MV_BLOB (id, blobdata)"
 . " VALUES (21, empty_blob()) RETURNING blobdata INTO :bd";

$result = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$blob = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);

oci_bind_by_name($result, ":bd", $blob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
oci_execute($result) or die ("Unable to execute query");


if (!$blob->save($image)) {
oci_rollback($conn);
}
else {
oci_commit($conn);
}


oci_free_statement($result);
$blob->free();
```

The entry is being inserted into the db, however, When I check this - it results to 0.

```
select round(DBMS_LOB.getlength(blobdata)/1024) kb from SCHEMA_A.MV_BLOB where id=21;
```

Comment: In addition to the answer given, also see the [OCI8 manual](https://www.php.net/manual/book.oci8.php)
and [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example from [Uploading and Displaying BLOBs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDPPH/ch_twelve_blobs.htm#TDPPH185)

```php
    public function insertBlob($sql, $action, $blobbindname, $blob, 
    $otherbindvars = array()) {
        $this->stid = oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);
        $dlob = oci_new_descriptor($this->conn, OCI_D_LOB);
        oci_bind_by_name($this->stid, $blobbindname, $dlob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
        foreach ($otherbindvars as $bv) {
            // oci_bind_by_name(resource, bv_name, php_variable, length)
            oci_bind_by_name($this->stid, $bv[0], $bv[1], $bv[2]);
        }
        oci_set_action($this->conn, $action);
        oci_execute($this->stid, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
        if ($dlob->save($blob)) {
            oci_commit($this->conn);
        }
    }
```

looks like your code should be something like this:

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO SCHEMA_A.MV_BLOB (id, blobdata)"
 . " VALUES (21, empty_blob()) RETURNING blobdata INTO :bd";

$result = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$blob = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);

oci_bind_by_name($result, "bd", $blob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB); // "bd" instead of ":bd"
// with OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT:
oci_execute($result, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT) or die ("Unable to execute query");

// and just to make it more clear
if ($blob->save($image)) {
    oci_commit($conn);
}
else {
    oci_rollback($conn);
}


oci_free_statement($result);
$blob->free();
```